# odoo domain filter many2many?

Tags: python, xml, filter, odoo

i'am added a car field in product template which related  to the car model that contains all cars, also i'am work in multi compny, and i'am also added a many2many relation with car model, 
all i need is to filter the cars in product template and display all cars that i have been assign in the company

this is my code

```
class cars(models.Model):
_name = 'cars'

name = fields.Char( string="Car",translate=True , required=True, ondelete='restrict')

class autopartscompany(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.company'

car_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="cars",string="Cars" )


class autopart(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

car = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="cars", store=True, string="Car", ondelete='restrict', required=False, domain="[('name','=', self.company_id.car_ids )]")
```

can any one help me how to define the domain filter correctly because that one give me error  Error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this the best solution to solve it

```
def _get_cars_domain(self):
    print (self.company_id.car_ids)
    return [('id', 'in', self.env.user.company_id.car_ids.ids)]

car = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="cars", store=True, string="Car", ondelete='restrict', required=False,domain=_get_cars_domain)
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a dynamic domain based on another field specially a many2many field that can hold
a lot of record, use onchange I think is the best way:

```py
class autopart(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    car = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="cars", store=True, string="Car", ondelete='restrict', required=False)

    # add the field itself to onchange to trigger this method in edit mode too
    @api.onchange('company_id', 'car') 
    def onchange_company(self):
        domain = []
        if self.company_id:
            domain.append(('id', 'in', self.company_id.car_ids.ids))
        return {'domain': {'car': domain}
```

Comment: thank you very much dear it worked well , but please can you descripe the code i need to know how it works

Comment: When ever you change the value of one of the two field,  company_id or car this will trigger this function witch returns a dictionary this dictionary will be send back to the client side, and the client side know what to do with it based on the keys of dictionary. For example here we indecated that we need to change the domain of car field.

Comment: you answer worked well i'am also tried to solve it by this 
    def _get_cars_domain(self):
        print (self.company_id.car_ids)
        return [('id', 'in', self.env.user.company_id.car_ids.ids)]